# PhpMyAdmin keeps redirecting to login screen

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm having troubles logging in to PhpMyAdmin. When I press "login" after typing in my credentials, it just keeps going back to the login screen. I could login perfectly a few days ago. I don't know what I've done that's causing this.

I can login to mysql perfectly in the shell (`mysql -D database -u user -ppassword`). My sites are running as expected. What could this be?

Logging in works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome or IE See reply #4 in this topic: https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/forums/forum/72909/topic/4479151

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache in Chrome and IE?

Comment: yes I have cleared the cache

Answer (score 3):

Probably what happened is you opened a URL and the browser was redirected to the login page. But when you log in, the redirect is still cached (because PMA doesn't specify not to cache it). If you have submitted the login form, try reloading the page and it should let you in.

Comment: thx for the reply, i tried what you said, but didn't work. Cleared the cache in Chrome and IE

Answer (score 2):

After googling this issue for ages I finally figured out what it was in my case. The problem was that google chrome does a validity check against the timestamp of the cookie (or something like this). Simply make sure that the server with PMA installed on it has the correct date/time settings and isn't out of sync. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I kept running into this issue, then I realized that the hard drive on my server was full.  This kept my PHP session information from storing (thus bouncing me back to the login page over and over).  After clearing off some hard drive space, I was able to login again successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and found out, that "empty cache and hard reload" function (long-press reload button) does not remove cached redirects or whatever phpmyadmin uses there.
You have to clear cache in "clear browsing data" menu.